# Multilingual sites in Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I'am new to Sitecore and had few questions on Multilingual sites in Sitecore

First I added the new language to the existing site and try to access the same with sc* parameter for testing purpose.

The site throws "Input string is in incorrect format" error. Though the content is not added for this it should be a blank page, not sure why it's throwing the error.

Comment: Could you give us some code/exception details, it's a little unclear what you're asking about. Do you mean you tried to access an item in the new language through a published website, even though it wasn't created/published, and the site threw an exception?

Comment: Did you set the "sc_lang" parameter correctly to the new language or did you try something else that Sitecore didn't understand?

Answer (score 0):

If, by chance, your Sitecore instance has multiple sites (i.e. you're using the SiteDefinition.config file to define separate site host headers) then you need to specify the language per-site, in the `language` attribute within the particular site node in SiteDefinition.config.

The value would be the language code, like "en-US" or "da-DK" for instance. For reference, see [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Adding%20New%20Site/site%20Attribute%20Properties.aspx) (this references the web.config, but it applies to SiteDefinition.config as well).

Answer (score 0):

besides the sc_lang query parameter, you can also give the language in the url.
for example /en leads to English homepage, /nl-NL to the dutch homepage. the first part of the url is the language.

so /en/page1.asp leads to the en version of the page1 item under your home.

The current language is stored in a cookie check the website#lang cookie.. Where website is the name of the website.

The default language is located in the web.config or include files

With the LinkManager in the web.config  you can configer the appearance